# How to know the transmission sucess rate of Wi-Fi acess points?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

I am using Linux. I hope to collect statistics of Wi-Fi access points near by.

E.g. For RSSI, I can collect them with `iwlist interface scanning`.

Now I am wondering if there is any tool that I can use to know the transmission success rate of these APs without really connecting to them and doing packet sending tests.

Answer (score 0):

If the APs in question support the "STA Statistics" request/report functionality of IEEE 802.11k Radio Resource Measurement, you could use that to read their counters for things like transmissions, failures, retransmission, etc. However, I don't know of any tool for doing this automatically, and in my experience 802.11k is not widely implemented (some enterprise-class APs probably do it).

If you could put a wireless packet sniffer somewhere that it was sure to see almost all frames from the AP, you could watch for what percentage of frames have the "retry" bit set. It would be a bit tedious compiling these statistics from, say, a packet capture in Wireshark. I don't know of a tool that makes this easy, but one could conceivably be written.